# How to get address from my location in Android

Tags: android, location, geocoding, fatal-error

I have a problem when I want to get the address from my location. I don't know where is the problem, this is my stacktrace:

> 08-14 18:06:41.035 29629-29629/com.cmn.cmnvtc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                   Process: com.cmn.cmnvtc, PID: 29629
>                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:260)
>                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:313)
>                                                                       at com.cmn.cmnvtc.Trajetlibre$2.onClick(Trajetlibre.java:122)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
>                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

and : the part of my code where there is the problem:

```
maPosition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getActivity());
                getLocation();
                List<Address> list = null;
                try {
                        list = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                        if (list!= null) {
                                Address returnedAddress = list.get(0);
                                start_address.setText(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + returnedAddress.getPostalCode() + " " + returnedAddress.getLocality());
                        } else {
                                start_address.setText("No Address returned!");
                        }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        start_address.setText("Cannot get address");
                }

        }
});
```

Can you help to find the problem?

@Poger Something like that ?

```
maPosition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getActivity());
                       List<Address> list = null;
                       try {
                           list = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                           //  start_address.setText(Double.toString(lat));
                           if(list!= null && !list.isEmpty()) {
                               Address returnedAddress = list.get(0);
                               StringBuilder adressBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                               adressBuilder.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + returnedAddress.getPostalCode() + " " + returnedAddress.getLocality());
                               getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void run() {
                                       start_address.setText("No Address returned!");
                                   }
                                   //job done on the UI thread
                               });
                           }
                           else{
                               getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void run() {
                                       start_address.setText("No Address returned!");
                                   }
                                   //job done on the UI thread
                               });
                           }
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               }).start();

            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't understand all what you said but when i run my app, and  just before click on the button I turn off the gps and I turn on it after, I get a result. Any idea?

Comment: Try the code in a background thread, hope your problem will be solved. I did the same thing and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.
Let's look at the [documentation of getFromLocation method in Geocoder class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)). In returns section it states:

> a list of Address objects. Returns **null** or **empty list** if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

Your code handles only the null case. It does not check whether the returned list is empty. Later when you call: `list.get(0)` - you may easily bump into IndexOutOfBoundsException.

The documentation also states:

> It may be useful to call this method from a thread separate from your primary UI thread.

It looks like you are calling this method from the UI thread. As you can see - you shouldn't. You should call `getFromLocation` on the background thread and then call `start_address.setText()` on the UI thread.

So, in first place you should change your code to something like this:

```
 list = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
 if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
     Address returnedAddress = list.get(0);
     //...
```

And secondly, `getFromLocation(...)` should be called in the background thread. You can do it it with code which can look similar to this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         //job done on a background thread, e.g. getFromLocation() call
     }
}).start();
```

And one more thing - if I assume correctly that `start_address` is an instance of TextView then `start_address.setText("No Address returned!");` should be called on the UI thread. When operating on the background thread, in Android one of the ways to achieve it is via [runOnUiThread() method of Activity class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)):

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    //job done on the UI thread
});
```

You can read more about processes and threads in Android in [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Comment: Can you give any of my code corrected, please? I have a poor english and i don't understand all you told